# How to store number of years, months and days in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-9.5

How to store number of years, months and days in PostgreSQL ?

Example: the life time of bulb is => 3 years, 4 months, 23 days

Is there any data type in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [interval data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) here you can find a guide to start with: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-interval/

```
CREATE TABLE components
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name CHARACTER VARYING(30),
  lifetime INTERVAL
)
INSERT INTO components(id, name, lifetime) VALUES(1,'bulb','3 years 4 months 23 days 3 hours 2 minutes 1 second');
```

Comment: That's a very specific lifetime for a light bulb ;)